# How to assert class overrides default __hash__ and __eq__

Tags: python

I'm writing a class decorator in python. As part of the decorator I would like to assert that the class does not use the default `__eq__` and `__hash__` methods. How can I do this?

```
@identifer # should throw AssertionError
class X(object):
    pass
```

I've explored these (besides googling, and looking in docs):

```
hasattr(X, '__eq__') # True :(

xeq, oeq = X.__eq__, object.__eq__
xeq is oeq # False :(
xeq == oeq # False :(

'__eq__' in X.__dict__ # False :)?
```

Testing the class's `__dict__` appears to work, but it doesn't seem to work if the class inherits the methods from a super class. So I *could* traverse the inheritance graph looking for the methods, but I want to know if there is a cleaner implementation first.

This is in 2.7, but would also like it to work in 3.x

Comment: Presumably, you don't actually care that a function overrides the __eq__ method - only that two semantically-identical instances are considered equal. So why not test the behaviour of an `==` check?

Comment: It's in a class decorator, so there are presumably no instances yet. And, I have no idea what to pass to the constructor

Comment: You have to traverse the inheritance graph, because you don’t actually want to take *all* bases into account—namely you don’t want the methods from the ``object`` base, appearantly, otherwise ``hasattr`` would be the way to go

Comment: Your title seems inconsistent with your question. Do you want to assert that the class itself overrides `__hash__` and `__eq__`, or do you want to assert that some class in its inheritance hierarchy does so?

Comment: Also, are you aware that in Python 2.x, `object` does not actually implement `__eq__`? `object.__eq__` is actually an instance method of the `object` object itself; it's called for `object == whatever`, not `object() == whatever`.

Comment: Also, what is the actual problem you’re trying to solve? Because it is possible that solutions suggested here (such as the one from Martijn Pieters), won’t work for you. If you need e.g. hashabiliy, you also need to chech that ``__eq__`` and ``__hash__`` are actually callables

Comment: @user2357112 But the method *must* be declared in the object *class*, so it is correct to search the classes ``__dict__`` for the method.

Comment: @JonasWielicki: No, seriously. Try `'__eq__' in object.__dict__` to see for yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57656/discussion-between-jonas-wielicki-and-user2357112).

Comment: @user2357112: sure, but in Python 3 it does, so if this is to work across both major versions then you need to test for it anyway. :-)

Comment: @user2357112 clarified the title

Comment: @JonasWielicki: if `__eq__` is not callable, then that's an error. Assigning `None` to `__hash__` is supported to indicate that an object is not hashable, so it *doesn't have to be callable*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah right, thanks. I was thinking about disabling hashability, indeed, but didn’t remember that it must be ``__hash__`` which is set to ``None``.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the whole class hierarchy needs to count, you could use:

```
all('__eq__' not in cls.__dict__ for cls in X.mro() if cls is not object)
```

This only returns True if there is no `__eq__` attribute in any of the classes in the MRO, except for `object`. This won't work for old-style Python 2 classes, as they don't have a [`class.mro()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.mro), however.

Comment: Perfect! Much nicer after adding the `mro()` part!